# why the parameter does not show in Axios requests?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, axios, razor-pages

I got following code to setup urls for Axios requests.
In razor page, I have this.

```
 var urls = {
     Value1Validate: '@Url.Action("Method1", "ControlerName1")',
     Value2Validate: '@Url.Action("Method2", "ControlerName2")',
 };
```

In js file, I have code as below. Anyone could help me find out why this elem.val() parameter value could not be passed to the action 2?

```
App.Value2OnChange = (e) => {
    let elem = $(e);
    alert("parameter value " + elem.val());
    axios.get(`${urls.Value2Validate}${elem.val()}`).then((response) => {
        if (response.data === 'ok') {
            dispay msg ('PASSED');
        } else {
            dispay msg ('Failed');
        }
    });
}
```

Here are the code in Controller2.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Method2(string parameterValue)
{
    var response = await MediatR.Send(new ValidateionQuery(parameterValue)));
    return JsonSuccess(response ? "ok" : "error");
}
```

Comment: What is the resulting URL being requested?  Did you just forget to give a key to the query string value?

Comment: I did some edit on the question.

Comment: That edit doesn't answer my question though... What is the resulting URL being used in the AJAX operation?  (Your browser's debugging tools can help you observing this information.)  Does it match what you expect?  At a glance, you're creating a URL for an action called `Method2`, but your actual action method is called `Value2Validate`.

Comment: more edit and the url will be .... /controller2/method2 ...  The issue is that parameter elem.val() is not passed

Comment: When you debug the JavaScript code in your browser, what is the value of `urls.Value2Validate`?  Because if it's `/controller2/method2` then clearly `elem.val()` is simply an empty string.  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: in js, the alert did show correct.  I just do not get why this value not passed ...  somewhere wrong?

Comment: Then you're providing conflicting information.  In one statement you indicate that `elem.val()` doesn't produce a value, in another you indicate that it does.  This conflicting information, combined with the edit history of the question and the (now deleted) previous comments, demonstrates that you're (1) not showing your actual code but just text that might kind of look like that code, and (2) not debugging anything but instead just making assumptions.  We can't help with that.  You are encouraged to provide a [mcve] of the problem and start using your debugging tools.

Comment: what debug tool do u used? how to debug the value passed in axios?

Comment: If you're not familiar with your browser's debugging tools, now would be a good time to start.  For example, in Chrome you can press F12 or find the developer tools in the browser's menu(s).  Your favorite search engine can help you find tutorials and resources for how to use these tools.  Actually using debugging tools and actually observing the runtime behaviors and values in your code will be much more useful than the apparent assumptions and guesses you've been making so far.

Comment: any good site or video to show?  thanks

Comment: Apparently, I did not pass the parameter value in the code axios.get(`${urls.Value2Validate}${elem.val()}`).  It only shows ${urls.Value2Validate} part without ${elem.val()}.

Comment: Again, your favorite search engine can help you find tutorials and resources for how to use these tools.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the parameter like below:

```
axios.get(`${urls.Value2Validate}?parameterValue=${encodeURIComponent(elem.val())}`)
```

Or

```
axios.get(`${urls.Value2Validate}`, {
    params: {
        parameterValue: elem.val(), 
    }
})
```